# How to add custom styles to an npm react component

Tags: reactjs

I am using font picker react and id like to customize the style of the button.. Maybe i need to download from github and customize it within the actual component, or maybe i am missing something simple about how to style something like this.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/font-picker-react

That is the package, you can see what the button looks like. I want to change the height width and color styles of the button and dropdown

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the [source](https://github.com/samuelmeuli/font-picker-react/blob/master/src/FontPicker.tsx) you can see the class names that are being rendered

```
(
  <div
    id={`font-picker${this.fontManager.selectorSuffix}`}
    className={expanded ? "expanded" : ""}
  >
    <button
      type="button"
      className="dropdown-button"
      onClick={this.toggleExpanded}
      onKeyPress={this.toggleExpanded}
    >
      <p className="dropdown-font-family">{activeFontFamily}</p>
      <p className={`dropdown-icon ${loadingStatus}`} />
    </button>
    {loadingStatus === "finished" && this.generateFontList(fonts)}
  </div>
);
```

The selectors used aren't that great, but that's what you can work with to add some css that targets `font-picker`. You can add a wrapper to target it specifically

```
<div className="font-picker">
  <FontPicker />
</div>

// the classnames that are exposed
.font-picker {
  // assuming you can nest selectors in sass/scss
  div.expanded {}
  .dropdown-button {}
  p.dropdown-font-family {}
}
```

Comment: I still cant change the background color of the button?

Comment: @mango my example assumes you have sass/scss and can nest selectors. if not, try using `.font-picker .dropdown-button {}` as your selector

Comment: Yea that selector works for the text color, border-radius, etc.. but i cant change the background color from grey